# awk regular expression: everything until nth occurence

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I'm trying to get my hands on `awk`. 
Given a string `s` (or many lines of strings of the form as `s`):

```
s=J0FKLSJ:FDSK:FDS212:43221G:FSSSS
```

**Q:** I am looking for an `awk` *regular expression* to get everything between (and including) the second character and until the *nth* occurrence of a character, e.g. `:` (excluding the last occurrence).

The output example for `n=3` is:

```
0FKLSJ:FDSK:FDS212
```

UPDATE:
Many good suggestions. They all work fine ( and I learned a bit). Ended up with @mklement0's, here in its most simpel form:

```
s=J0FKLSJ:FDSK:FDS212:43221G:FSSSS
echo $s | awk -F: -v n=3 '{ for(i=1;i<=n;++i) s = s (s=="" ? "" : FS) $i; print substr(s, 2) }'
```

Comment: Does it have to be awk?

Comment: also, showing some of your attempts is welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A concise regex-based solution requires the use of capture groups, which many Awk implementations do not support; notably, capture groups are not part of the [POSIX Awk spec.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)

***GNU* `awk`**, however, does support **capture groups** via its (nonstandard) [`gensub` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html):

```
awk -v n=3 '{ s = gensub("^.(([^:]*:){" n "}).*$", "\\1", 1); sub(".$", "", s); print s}' \
  <<<'J0FKLSJ:FDSK:FDS212:43221G:FSSSS'
```

<sup>The first char. is excluded by the `.` placed *before* the start of the capture group (`(...)`).  The capture group invariably includes the trailing `:`, which the later `sub()` call removes; a more verbose, but more efficient alternative to the `sub` approach is

`print substr(s, 1, length(s)-1)}`</sup>

By contrast, the standard `sub` and `gsub` functions do *not* support capture groups (via back-references such as `"\\1"`).

Note that `gensub` differs in other respects too: it *returns* the result of the substitution without modifying the input string, and it takes an additional parameter indicating whether the substitution should be global (`g` or `G`) or which match (by index; `1` here) should be targeted.

---

With **other Awk implementations** you could use a **field-based approach**, which is Awk's core strength:

```
awk -F: -v n=3 '{ for(i=1;i<=n;++i) s = s (s=="" ? "" : FS) $i; print substr(s, 2) }' \
  <<<'J0FKLSJ:FDSK:FDS212:43221G:FSSSS'
```

---

Both commands yield:

```
0FKLSJ:FDSK:FDS212
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F: '{sub(/s=J/,"");print $1,$2,$3}' OFS=: file

0FKLSJ:FDSK:FDS212
```

Comment: I believe the OP has a variable `$s` with the content `J0FKLSJ:FDSK:FDS212:43221G:FSSSS`. so it is about parsing this text instead of `s=...`.

Comment: Leaving the `s=` issue aside: the `OFS`-based approach is elegant, but it doesn't generalize well: it only works if you know the value of `n` (`3` here) ahead of time.

Comment: @mklement0 is right, it needs a loop: `awk -F: '{sub(/s=J/,"");for(;++i<=3;printf $i (i<3?OFS:ORS));}' OFS=: file` and maybe a variable `n`, left as an exersize.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `s=J0FKLSJ:FDSK:FDS212:43221G:FSSSS` in a file `foo` as the string (therefore `for(i=4;...)`);

```
$ awk -F '' '{for(i=4;a[":"]<3;a[$i]++)printf $(i++)}' foo
0FKLSJ:FDSK:FDS212
```

- `-F ''` separates each character on its own field so it's easy to loop thru with `for` and reference `$i` for outputing
- `;a[":"]<3;` we control the amount of `:`s
- `a[$i]++` is the counter for each char we've seen

If you want to use regex for it and you're using Gnu awk, you can use `match`:

```
$ awk '{match($0,/^([^:]*[:]){3}*/,a); gsub(/^...|.$/,"",a[0]); print a[0]}' bar
0FKLSJ:FDSK:FDS212
```

Comment: Just a heads-up for macOS users (as of macOS 10.12): annoyingly, `awk -F ''` causes an error ("awk: field separator FS is empty"); the workaround is to use a `BEGIN {FS=""}` block at the start of the Awk script instead.